# Outlet appears to be switched but switches don't work

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Hi all new to the Diy boards. If there's any more info I can post, I'm happy to.

I just purchased a house and have been replacing some outlets. A few of the existing ones had two red wires into the top outlet, two black wires into the bottom with a white neutral coming out of each. The tabs on the hot side are broken.  Based on some googling, this seems to mean they are half-switched.

I wired my new outlets exactly the same, including the broken tab. The outlets all work fine but don't seem to be attached to the switch. There are two switches that don't appear to do anything. These outlets could be attached to either, both, or neither. I am unable to tell. I did not think to confirm before starting that the switches worked. However my wiring is identical so I doubt they did.

Did I do something wrong in the wiring? I appreciate  any advice you can give.

Comment: Can you verify with a voltage tester that the wires going in are live? Also, I take it the hot side of the outlet works, just not the switched side?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm sure at least one of the wires are live because the outlets are hot. I guess I'm not sure if each individual wire is live. All I have at the moment is a contact less voltage detector. I'm headed to the hardware store and could get a more complex tool if necessary. For your second question, I'm not sure what you mean. Both outlets in the receptacle are live regardless of the state of the switches. (sorry, still very much a beginner)

Comment: It's possible that the original installation was a half-switched outlet, like you previously stated. However, over time maybe someone decided they no longer wanted that, so they could have jumpered the hot side and the switched side together in a different location. Perhaps in the switch box. That may be why it seems the switches don't do anything. That would make both sides of the outlet hot all the time.

Comment: @Mike That would make sense. Is there a way for me to verify that?

Comment: It's also possible that there is one single outlet somewhere  in the circuit without a broken tab.

Comment: @Skoberlink -- perhaps you could look in the switch box?

Comment: @Tyson do all outlets, even the ones that are wired normally, need the tabs broken?

Comment: If the are fed by both red and black they need the tab broken.

Comment: @Tyson that could definitely be the problem then. I'll have to check that when I get home.

Comment: I would take off the covers to the switch plate/s. Look to see if one of the switches has no wires connected to it. If I am correct, you may see a wire-nutted joint that looks like it may have been connected to the switch at one time. That might be hard to tell, though. If you see a joint that has a black and red tied together that would be a strong clue. You could break that joint apart to confirm. Be safe about it if you do....

Comment: @Tyson It looks like I just needed to break the tabs on the other ones in the series. They all work great now, thanks for the help on the newbie question! I still don't understand why some of them had two red and two black and some just had one though...

Comment: Each outlet had power come in on a red and black... then sent power to the next receptacle on a red and black.  The ones at the end didn't need that.

Comment: The locations with 2 red and 2 black have an IN and OUT wire, a single red and black means you have reached the last outlet and only IN is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a single outlet tab is left intact on series of 1/2 switched outlets, it will prevent the switched outlets from working correctly.  (The switched half outlets will also be always on also.)